# Kotlin compiler: Data binding error, cannot find method

Tags: kotlin, android-databinding

Mirgating from `Java` to `Kotlin` I try to use static function with `Data Binding`:

```
  <data>
    <import type="com.package.domain.tools.helper.StringValidator"/>
    ...
</data>
```

Then I call function `hideNumber`:

```
 <com.hastee.pay.ui.view.Text
        ...
        android:text='@{StringValidator.hideNumber(account.number)}'
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/number"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/number" />
```

Using databinding here causes error:

```
   [kapt] An exception occurred: 
android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding 
errors.
 ****/ data binding error ****msg:cannot find method 
 hideNumber(java.lang.String) in class 
 com.package.domain.tools.helper.StringValidator....
```

Here's this object:

```
 object StringValidator {
  ...
fun hideNumber(number: String): String {
    return "****" + number.substring(number.length - 4)
}
}
```

How can I reach this function using `Kotlin` and `Data Binding`?

Comment: try adding an `@JvmStatic` to `hideNumber`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The data binding compiler is looking for a static method.

Since a named `object` alone is not enough to make all methods inside that object `static`, you need an additional `@JvmStatic` annotation on your `hideNumber`-method:

```
@JvmStatic
fun hideNumber(number: String): String {
    return "****" + number.substring(number.length - 4)
}
```

see also: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-methods

Comment: Cool! Thanks for explanation!

Comment: Thanks guy. You save my day!!